Can apache2 proxy provide secure commnication with a server app that has no support for SSL?
I have a hosted VPS with apache2 and SSL certificate and key (free, certbot). In DNS I created two subdomains: www.myserver.org and rstudio.myserver.org.
Browser connection with https://www.myserver.org works fine. Now I want https://rstudio.myserver.org to securely connect to an rstudio server running on that same VPS.  This rstudio server has no SSL support (not supported in the free version). I was hoping that the apache proxy_mods might make it possible to have a secure connection with the rstudio server.
Is this even possible? My first experiments gave errors like "Invalid SSL handshake" so I'm a bit pessimistic. I was about to buy a pro license, but thought I might check here first.
Thanks for any advice.
Joachim
